# Как можно усовершенствовать код при поиске несколько полей?

Tags: vue.js

Я знаю что сделал костыль, но сделал примерно как бы код работал и показал как я хочу сделать.
То есть что я хочу получить от этого если не понятно, чтобы он искал в колонках фамилии, имя, отчество, телефоне и email значение которая указана в поиске.
Примерно убогая моя реализация выглядит так

```
/src/views/AppTest.vue:278
this.items
        .filter(item => {
          let search = this.search.toLowerCase();
          let name = item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search);
          let last_name = item.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(search);
          let patronymic = item.patronymic.toLowerCase().includes(search);
          let phone = item.phone.toLowerCase().includes(search);
          let email = item.email.toLowerCase().includes(search);

//Если что-то нашел у поле, то это он возвращает
          if (name) return name; 
          if (last_name) return last_name;
          if (patronymic) return patronymic;
          if (email) return email;
          if (phone) return phone;
        })
```

Много повторяющих моментов, но это из-за того что я не знаю как ее реализовать
вот как в песочнице это выглядит https://codesandbox.io/s/pyvjxxnnvj

Comment: Никак. У вас самый нормальный код.

Comment: Вы хотите отобрать наиболее подходящие под запрос элементы?

Answer (score 0):

```
let search = this.search.toLowerCase();
Object.keys(item).some(s => {
            if (
              s === "last_name" ||
              s === "name" ||
              s === "patronymic" ||
              s === "phone" ||
              s === "email"
            ) {
              return (
                String(item[s])
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf(search) > -1
              );
            }
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

Если цель состоит в том, чтобы отобрать наиболее подходящие под запрос элементы списка, то попробуйте подойти так:

```
let itemsWithSum = this.items.map(item => {
    let sum = 0;
    let search = this.search.toLowerCase();
    sum += item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search) ? 1 : 0;
    sum += item.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(search) ? 1 : 0;
    sum += item.patronymic.toLowerCase().includes(search) ? 1 : 0;
    sum += item.phone.toLowerCase().includes(search) ? 1 : 0;
    sum += item.email.toLowerCase().includes(search) ? 1 : 0;

    return {
        item: this.item,
        sum
    }
})
```

И теперь, когда у Вас элементы подшиты суммой, можно отобрать наиболее подходящие, а также отсортировать их в порядке убывания соответствия.

Вместо единиц можно указать другие положительные числа, которые будут говорить о значимости совпадения. Либо можно подставлять сюда длину строки! Чем длиннее слово, тем сильнее оно влияет на сумму при совпадении.

Конечно это грубый алгоритм. В реальности лучше считать сумму пробегая по массиву и отбирать только те элементы, сумма которых вытесняет хотя бы один элемент из N отобранных. То есть делать фильтрацию и оценку соответствия одновременно. Тогда сможете сэкономить и время, и память.